# Is there an aggregate function that could return first non-null value within a group?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I'm using Oracle XE 10g.

Please I beg you to read my question carefully. I have a weird use case for this but please bear with it.

Let's say I have the following records:

```
Table person
Name  YearOfBirth
a     null
a     2001
a     2002
b     1990
b     null
c     null
c     2001
c     2009
```

Basically if I do the following query:

```
select
  p.Name, max(p.YearOfBirth)
from
  person p
group by
  p.Name
```

That will give me records with distinct Names and each distinct name will be paired to maximum value of YearOfBirth within its group. In the given example the group where Name='a', the maximum YearOfBirth is 2002.

If max() is an aggregate function that returns the maximum value of a column in a given group, is there a function that returns the **first value within the group** that is not null? **Instead of giving me the maximum value, I want the first value you could find as long as it is not null.**

Please don't ask me why I can't simply use min() or max() instead.

Obviously I can't use rownum here as some might suggest because doing so will limit the number of groups I could get.

Comment: How do you define "first"?  Rows in a table don't have a defined order unless your table is an IOT (Index Organized Table) or you are processing rows returned from a SELECT with an "ORDER BY".

Comment: Please define _first_. Data in a table is unordered, the order that results are returned in could change at any time. The concept of first only makes sense if it can be defined in terms of the data.

Comment: @George3: Even in an IOT, there is no defined order and it is possible to get results back that are not in order by the primary key, especially if a fast full scan of the primary key index is performed. See: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4514641276987#5363322378640

Comment: @Shannon Severance - Good point no defined order in an IOT for _retrieval_, only ordered as defined for logical storage by primary key.

Comment: @Shannon Yeah, I know it doesn't make sense not to have a "spec" of retrieving the "first" row or it doesn't make sense not having a definite definition of the "first". But that's the point, the solution itself **should have no basis** of getting the first. That's exactly the "spec". I know it doesn't make sense but what the heck, it's a long story. Never had this use case before.

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, sometimes one just wants any distinct record; 'first' is not important in itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding why ROW NUMBER would not work for you.  I do not have Oracle, but I did test this in SQL Server, and I believe it provides the results you requested:

```
WITH soTable AS
(
   SELECT 'a' AS Name, null AS YearOfBirth
   UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 2001
   UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 2002
   UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 1990
   UNION ALL SELECT 'b', null
   UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 1994
   UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 1981
   UNION ALL SELECT 'c', null
   UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 2009
   UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 2001
)
, soTableNoNulls AS
(
   SELECT so.Name, so.YearOfBirth, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY so.Name ORDER BY so.Name ASC) AS RowNumber
   FROM soTable AS so
   WHERE so.YearOfBirth IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT nn.Name, nn.YearOfBirth
FROM soTableNoNulls AS nn
WHERE nn.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: I'm making the assumption here that there is a primary key driving order so the 'first' record would be consistent.

Comment: It doesn't look like you use the RowNumber column from soTableNoNulls. If it's not needed, would be best to remove. I think you could cut that down to one CTE instead of two. (Not counting the CTE with test data.) (CTE = Common Table Expression, usually called subquery factoring in Oracle.)

Comment: Thanks, noticed that too late after I posted the answer.  It's removed now.

Comment: Fantastic! I don't know how "Partition By" exactly works but you made it work. Thanks Adam. BTW, there's no primary key. It is possible to get more than one record with the same names and the same YearOfBirths. Would that be a problem?

Comment: Brent Ozar wrote a good post about how PARTITION BY works in ROW_NUMBER (his post has information on other aggregate functions as well) http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/07/leaving-windows-open/

Comment: Supertonsky,  I don't see there being an issue in this instance for you with having the same `Name` and `YearOfBirth`.  Your requirements state you need the first, so even if there are duplicates, this will still return the 'first' record for you.

Comment: Oracle's `first_value` will probably be quicker. I'd write an answer, but I still don't understand how OP is defining first. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions066.htm#i83212

Answer (score 2):

If by "first" you mean the record with the lowest birth year, then you can do the following:

```
WITH s1 AS
(
   SELECT 'a' AS name, NULL AS birth_year FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 2001 FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 2002 FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 1990 FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'b', null FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 1994 FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 1981 FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'c', null FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 2009 FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 2001 FROM dual
)
SELECT name, birth_year FROM (
    SELECT name, birth_year
         , FIRST_VALUE(birth_year IGNORE NULLS) OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY birth_year ) AS first_birth_year
      FROM s1
) WHERE birth_year = first_birth_year
```

The advantage of using `FIRST_VALUE()` over `ROW_NUMBER()` is that the former will return multiple rows in the event of ties. For example, if you had another `a` born in 2001 in your data, then the resulting data would look like this:

```
NAME  BIRTH_YEAR
a     2001
a     2001
b     1981
c     2001
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` solution would return only one of the above rows. However, that could also be solved by using `RANK()`.

If there is some other way of defining "first" (e.g., an entry date column), simply use that in the `ORDER BY` clause of `FIRST_VALUE()`.

Comment: Just FYI for the benefit of anyone looking for a T-SQL equivalent, this solution also works for SQL Server -  even though its FIRST_VALUE lacks  the IGNORE NULLS clause. You can simply ORDER BY the column DESC if the other values are all null. This helps avoid a lot of awkward joins in pivot queries, as I'm finding out first-hand right now (thanks for the solution)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION first_agg ( anyelement, anyelement )
RETURNS anyelement AS
$$
    SELECT $1;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
;
```

then:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE first (
        sfunc    = first_agg,
        basetype = anyelement,
        stype    = anyelement
);
```

test it:

```
select first((case when a = 1 then null else a end) ORDER BY a NULLS FIRST) from generate_series(1, 100) a; -- => "2"
```

Comment: Re-writing it in Plpgsql would make it 2x faster.

Comment: @GillBates Not sure about that. Have you tested it or have reason to claim so? I specifically used SQL because  it should be faster on the understanding that is well written out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/language-sql-vs-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions

Comment: Yes, it's based on practical experience.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while searching for a similar solution for MSSQL.

The main problem I had with the above solution is that it will omit any records that don't have any non-null values.

With the help from the answers here, combined with the answers from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66527979/259457), I came up with this solution for SQL Server:

```
WITH soTable AS (
  SELECT 'a' AS Name, null AS YearOfBirth
  UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 2001
  UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 2002
  UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 1990
  UNION ALL SELECT 'b', null
  UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 1994
  UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 1981
  UNION ALL SELECT 'c', null
  UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 2009
  UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 2001
  UNION ALL SELECT 'd', null
)
SELECT
  Name,
  SUBSTRING(STRING_AGG(YearOfBirth, '|'), 1, CHARINDEX('|', STRING_AGG(YearOfBirth, '|'))-1) AS YearOfBirth
FROM
  soTable
GROUP BY
  Name;
```