# MySQL get first non null value after group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have a large table with data that is not unique but needs to be. This table is a result of multiple union selects so is not an actual table. I cannot make it an actual table for other reasons.

All of the UNION'd tables have an email column which will eventually be unique. The resulting records look like this:

```
1   ozzy@test.com   Ozzy
2   test@test.com   Tony
3   test@yahoo.com  Steve
4   tiny@test.com   
13  tony@gmail.com  Tony
14  test@test.com   Ozzy
15  test@yahoo.com  Dave
16  tiny@test.com   Tim
```

As you can see, some emails appear more then once with different names or non-existent names. When I add a `GROUP BY email` clause at the end, the results look like this:

```
1   ozzy@test.com   Ozzy
2   test@test.com   Tony
3   test@yahoo.com  Steve
4   tiny@test.com   
13  tony@gmail.com  Tony
```

As you can see, email 4 does not have a name because it chose the first entry with `NULL` for a name. Then I tried to use `GROUP_CONCAT` which made the results look like this:

```
1   ozzy@test.com   Ozzy
14  test@test.com   Ozzy,Tony
15  test@yahoo.com  Dave,Steve
16  tiny@test.com   Tim
13  tony@gmail.com  Tony
```

As you can see, now everyone has a name but some rows have more then one name concatenated. What I want to do is `GROUP BY email` and choose the first `NOT NULL` entry of each column for each row to theoretically look like so:

```
1   ozzy@test.com   Ozzy
2   test@test.com   Tony
3   test@yahoo.com  Steve
4   tiny@test.com   Tim
13  tony@gmail.com  Tony
```

I have tried using `COALESCE` but it doesn't work as intended. My current query looks like so:

```
SELECT
    id,
    email,
    `name`
FROM
(
    SELECT
        email,
        `name`
    FROM
        multiple_tables_and_unions
) AS emails

GROUP BY email
```

I have removed the code from the temporary table as it contains many tables but all select the `email` and `name` column. Essentially I need a function like `GROUP_COALESCE` but unfortunately it does not exist. What are my options?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try using `MAX`, like this:

```
SELECT
    email,
    MAX(`name`)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        email,
        `name`
    FROM
        multiple_tables_and_unions
) AS emails

GROUP BY email
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answer is the best :) I always assumed MAX worked only on numbers. Thanks

Comment: Smart one! Like it

Comment: little nugget. old but gold

Comment: But will this pick the first non null value? I doubt! It will pick the max value order by alphabet. Also it will do the same if we have int value instead of string.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri the OP wanted to skip NULLs and pick a non-NULL value instead, didn't specifically wanted the MAX value.

Comment: But they did specify that they need first non null value. Check my below answer, may be that is more accurate in that terms.

Answer (score 3):

To select the first `non null` value, `GROUP_CONCAT` can be handy here. Below is the example:

```
SELECT
    email,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`name`), ',',1)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        email,
        `name`
    FROM
        multiple_tables_and_unions
) AS emails

GROUP BY email;
```