# Merge two rows if one of them contains a column that is null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
cusstomerID; EMail, Telefon, Fax
2; s@l.com; 0123; NULL      
2; s@l.com; NULL; 456       
3, p@y.com; 01792494976; NULL       
3; p@y.com; NULL; 01792494977
4; a@c.com; 0167578252; NULL        
5; qr@g.com; 069-541111; NULL   
5; qr@g.com; NULL; 069-541222   
6; cv@gv.com; NULL; 0123456
```

Expected Outcome:

```
cusstomerID; EMail, Telefon, Fax
2; s@l.com; 0123; 456
3, p@y.com; 01792494976; 01792494977
4; a@c.com; 0167578252; NULL        
5; qr@g.com; 069-541111; 069-541222 
6; cv@gv.com; NULL; 0123456
```

There are always 2 rows for every costumer in my data base when the customer has a telefon and a Fax Number (when the customer has only one of the 2 he/she has only one row): In the first row, the fax number is empty and in the second the telefone number is empty: how can I put it in one row? Via (my)SQL

I just want to `update` the table - not create a new one :)

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Isn't there any primary key in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it possible, you have to join the table to be able to choose the right field depending on value.

```
SELECT cusstomerID, EMail, IFNULL(t1.Telefon, t2.Telefon), IFNULL(t1.Fax, t2.Fax)
FROM tablename t1 
JOIN tablename t2 ON t1.cusstomerID = t2.cusstomerID
```

And to clean your table, you can do something like this :

```
UPDATE FROM tablename t1, tablename t2
SET t1.Telefon = IFNULL(t1.Telefon, t2.Telefon)
[...]
WHERE t1.cusstomerID = t2.cusstomerID ;

DELETE FROM tablename 
WHERE ( Telefon IS NULL
OR Fax IS NULL ) 
AND cusstomerID IN ( 
    SELECT cusstomerID 
    FROM tablename 
    GROUP BY cusstomerID 
    HAVING COUNT(cusstomerID ) = 2
);
```

Or you can create a new table and delete the older with a `CREATE TABLE AS` statement.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename2 AS ( SELECT t1.customerssID, t1.EMail, IFNULL( t1.Telefon, t2.Telefon ) AS Telefon, IFNULL( t1.Fax, t2.Fax ) AS Fax
```

FROM tablename t1
JOIN tablename t2 ON t1.customerssID = t2.customerssID );

Then you can `DELETE` the old table

```
DELETE tablename;
```

And rename the new one.

```
RENAME TABLE tablename2 tablename;
```

**EDIT : use `MAX` with `GROUP BY`**

After some research, I found this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782932/mysql-get-first-non-null-value-after-group-by) which makes [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh) answer correct. So the answer can be :

```
CREATE TABLE tablename2 AS ( SELECT `cusstomerID`, `EMail`, MAX(`Telefon`), MAX(`Fax`)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY `cusstomerID` );
```

Then you can `DELETE` the old table

```
DELETE tablename;
```

And rename the new one.

```
RENAME TABLE tablename2 tablename;
```

Comment: I just want to update the table - not create a new one :)

Comment: `SELECT`won't create a new table... See basics of SQL to understand

Comment: Ok- but how can I reinsert the new result into the existing table?

Comment: But the data is in the same table: how can I join when there is only one table?

Comment: Ok-I think my data set is too big to solve it this way (about 350k rows): Is there any faster way?

Comment: You can do it in a script (in a programmation langage like PHP or PERL)

Comment: This would definately exceed my knowledge :(

Comment: Did you try the `CREATE TABLE ... AS` statement? I think it is the best way.

Comment: it´s not working it always says:    "Error Code: 1166. Incorrect column name 'IFNULL(t1.Telefon, t2.Telefon)'

Comment: just abbreviate that column with your own choosed name

Comment: I did-just changed it again for you

Comment: seems like create table and IFNULL are not compatible

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Look at the response of Emile Holub ... You have to alias columns in the `SELECT` to be able to create the table. I've corrected my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 t1,table1 t2 set t1.Telefon=t2.Telefon,t2.fax='delete' where t1.cusstomerID=t2.cusstomerID and t1.fax is not null and t2.Telefon is not null;

delete from table1 where fax='delete' and Telefon is not null;
```

Change the table name and try it.