# LANGUAGE SQL vs LANGUAGE plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

Am very new in *Database development* so I have some doubts regarding my following example:

Function f1() - ***language sql***

```
 create or replace function f1(istr  varchar)
 returns text as $$ 
 select 'hello! '::varchar || istr;
 $$ language sql;
```

Function f2() - ***language plpgsql***

```
 create  or replace function f2(istr  varchar)
 returns text as $$ 
 begin select 'hello! '::varchar || istr; end;
 $$ language plpgsql;
```

- Both *functions* can be called like `select f1('world')` or `select f2('world')`.
- If I call `select f1('world')` the *output* will be:

  ```
   `hello! world`
  ```
- And *output* for `select f2('world')`:

  > ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
  > HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
  > CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function f11(character varying) line 2 at SQL statement
  > ********** Error **********
- I wish to know the difference and in which situations I should use `language sql` or `language plpgsql`.

Any useful link or answers regarding functions will much appreciated.

Comment: _any usefull link or answers regarding functions will much appreciated_ Who would ever think about the manual? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-programming.html

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto _someone may lazy to find out or not able to find out the correct solutions...!!_

Comment: @keet You may want to read this chapter of the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html It contains full description of PL/pgSQL language with examples.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto PostgreSQL-Guide was reviewd many times, is a good text; but there are no "open [stakeholder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stakeholder_engagement) curation" and no [crowdsourcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing) mechanism to enhance it. So: PostgreSQL is bad (!) for many users and many kinds of use.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

### [**SQL functions**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html)

... are the better choice:

- For **simple scalar queries**. Not much to plan, better save any overhead.
- For **single (or very few) calls per session**. Nothing to gain from plan caching via prepared statements that PL/pgSQL has to offer. See below.
- If they are typically called in the context of bigger queries and are simple enough to be [**inlined**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions).
- For lack of **experience** with any procedural language like PL/pgSQL. Many know SQL well and that's about all you need for SQL functions. Few can say the same about PL/pgSQL. (Though it's rather simple.)
- A bit shorter code. No block overhead.

### [**PL/pgSQL functions**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)

... are the better choice:

- When you need any **procedural elements** or **variables** that are not available in SQL functions, obviously.
- For any kind of **dynamic SQL**, where you build and [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) statements dynamically. Special care is needed to avoid SQL injection. More details:

  - [Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684)
- When you have **computations** that can be **reused** in several places and a CTE can't be stretched for the purpose. In an SQL function you don't have variables and would be forced to compute repeatedly or write to a table. This related answer on dba.SE has side-by-side **code examples** for solving the same problem using an SQL function / a plpgsql function / a query with CTEs:

  - [How to pass a parameter into a function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71442/3684)

  Assignments are somewhat more expensive than in other procedural languages. Adapt a programming style that doesn't use more assignments than necessary.
- When a function cannot be inlined and is called repeatedly. Unlike with SQL functions, [**query plans can be cached** for all SQL statements inside a PL/pgSQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING); they are treated like **prepared statements**, the plan is cached for repeated calls within the same session (if Postgres expects the cached (generic) plan to perform better than re-planning every time. That's the reason why PL/pgSQL functions are ***typically faster*** after the first couple of calls in such cases.

  Here is a thread on pgsql-performance discussing some of these items:

  - [Re: pl/pgsql functions outperforming sql ones?](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/0238E40E527049828C48675488422F6D@CAPRICA#0238E40E527049828C48675488422F6D@CAPRICA)
- When you need to [**trap errors**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).
- For [**trigger functions**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).
- When including DDL statements changing objects or altering system catalogs in any way relevant to subsequent commands - because all statements in SQL functions are parsed at once while PL/pgSQL functions plan and execute each statement sequentially (like a prepared statement). See:

  - [Why can PL/pgSQL functions have side effect, while SQL functions can't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004980/why-can-pl-pgsql-functions-have-side-effect-while-sql-functions-cant/51033884#51033884)

Also consider:

- [PostgreSQL Stored Procedure Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684)

---

To actually *return* from a PL/pgSQL function, you could write:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f2(istr varchar)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN 'hello! ';  -- defaults to type text anyway
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

There are other ways:

- [Can I make a plpgsql function return an integer without using a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169676/can-i-make-a-plpgsql-function-return-an-integer-without-using-a-variable/8169928#8169928)
- [The manual on "Returning From a Function"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

Comment: Well said; I forgot to mention dynamic SQL, too.

Comment: Thanks. I guess there is one difference not mentioned in your reply. Is it correct that a SQL function can't contain any command which alter the system catalog, such as `CREATE TABLE`, while a PL/pgSQL function can?  What is the reason? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004980/what-is-the-order-between-parsing-and-execution-of-pl-pgsql-functions

Comment: @Ben: Not exactly. SQL functions *can* contain DDL commands. You just need to be aware of implications. And some combinations of commands don't work. I added an answer over there.

Answer (score 25):

[PL/PgSQL is a PostgreSQL-specific procedural language based on SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html). It has loops, variables, error/exception handling, etc. Not all SQL is valid PL/PgSQL - as you discovered, for example, you can't use `SELECT` without `INTO` or `RETURN QUERY`. PL/PgSQL may also be used in `DO` blocks for one-shot procedures.

[`sql` functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) can only use pure SQL, but they're often more efficient and they're simpler to write because you don't need a `BEGIN ... END;` block, etc. SQL functions may be inlined, which is not true for PL/PgSQL.

People often use PL/PgSQL where plain SQL would be sufficient, because they're used to thinking procedurally. In most cases when you think you need PL/PgSQL you probably actually don't. Recursive CTEs, lateral queries, etc generally meet most needs.

For more info ... see the manual.

Comment: True, set based solutions are typically superior. But that's no final verdict in whether to use an SQL or a PL/pgSQL function. Newcomers are sometimes using plpgsql for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 1):

just make the select query you wrote inside the function as the returned value:

```
 create  or replace function f2(istr  varchar)
 returns text as $$ 
 begin return(select 'hello! '::varchar || istr); end;
 $$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: There is no need for the SELECT statement if this context. RETURN 'hello! '::varchar || istr; is quite enough. The pure SQL version (without begin... return ... end...) is likely to be much more efficient anyway.