# Force PostgreSQL to use different schema in functions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, search-path

I wanted to make an update function for a schema in PG SQL database. A test function is below. It doesn't work because it should never raise a notice, but will do that when running `test_schema_update('second')`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_schema_update(my_schema_name VARCHAR(200)) 
RETURNS void AS
$__marker__$
DECLARE
    actualValue varchar(1000);
    testValue varchar(1000);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SET search_path TO ' || quote_ident(my_schema_name);

    testValue := (SELECT max(value) FROM setting WHERE settingkey = 'libraryname');
    EXECUTE ('SELECT max(value) FROM setting WHERE settingkey = ''libraryname''')
        INTO actualValue;

    IF (actualValue != testValue)
    THEN
        RAISE NOTICE '% != %', actualValue, testValue;
        RAISE INFO 'Schema was: %', current_schema();
    END IF;

    RESET search_path;
END;
$__marker__$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

test_schema_update('first');
test_schema_update('second');
```

The problem is that PG SQL seem to analyze `SELECT` statements only once per session and then tables are fixed to specific schema. What is interesting is that you will get `Schema was: second`.

So is there a way reset `SELECT` statement analysis or some other way to work around this?

Side note: All schema creation function (`ALTER TABLE`, `CREATE TABLE`...) work fine. Only data manipulation functions seem to be affected (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`).

### Workaround

Before:

```
IF (
    SELECT max(id) FROM dimtime
)
THEN
    INSERT INTO dimtime SELECT * FROM public.src_dimtime;
END IF;
```

After:

```
EXECUTE ('
    SELECT max(id) FROM dimtime
')
INTO testInt;
IF (testInt IS NULL)
THEN
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO dimtime SELECT * FROM public.src_dimtime';
END IF;
```

**Edit**: The problem occurs in PostgreSQL 9.2, but seem not to occur in 9.3. Maybe it was fixed?

Comment: That syntax only allows a static schema to be set (not from a parameter).

Comment: This should work; dump please `s1 := current_schema()` vs. `execute 'select current_schema()' into s2` & tag the specific postgres version -- don't use `RESET` (that won't re-set the previous configuration, the default will be restored), use `SET LOCAL` instead at start, so you can leave `RESET`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That behaviour is to be expected. The reason is that PL/pgSQL uses **plan caching** for SQL statements, internally using standard **prepared statements**.

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING)

> As each expression and SQL command is first executed in the function,
>   the PL/pgSQL interpreter creates a prepared execution plan (using the
>   SPI manager's `SPI_prepare` and `SPI_saveplan` functions). Subsequent
>   visits to that expression or command reuse the prepared plan.

This is also the reason, why plpgsql functions are often *faster* than plain SQL functions for complex operations:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

Prepared statements are saved for the lifetime of the **session**, not just the transaction (but invalidated when underlying objects change, this is safe with concurrent access). [The documentation once again:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING)

> Once PL/pgSQL has made an execution plan for a particular command in a
>   function, it will reuse that plan for the **life of the database
>   connection**. This is usually a win for performance, but it can cause
>   some problems if you dynamically alter your database schema.

Bold emphasis mine.

If you want to "change" the schema of a table name, you are really going to refer to a completely different table and ***need*** to use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`, which generates a new plan every time (with all advantages and disadvantages):

> Because PL/pgSQL saves execution plans in this way, SQL commands that
>   appear directly in a PL/pgSQL function must refer to the same tables
>   and columns on every execution; that is, you cannot use a parameter as
>   the name of a table or column in an SQL command. To get around this
>   restriction, you can construct dynamic commands using the PL/pgSQL
>   `EXECUTE` statement — at the price of constructing a new execution plan
>   on every execution.

Read the referenced chapter in the manual. It's quite comprehensive.

#### Code example

You don't need dynamic SQL for your added code example, and a single statement will be faster:

```
INSERT INTO dimtime  -- you may want list columns
SELECT *             -- here as well
FROM   public.src_dimtime
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dimtime);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've manged to workaround this restrictions, but EXECUTE on everything is quite painful (added example in my question).

Comment: @Nux: You don't need `EXECUTE` on *everything*. Only the statements where tables / columns are changed dynamically. The example in your question can be plain SQL - and simplified. I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: I'm making update of many schemas at a time. In other words there is `client1.dimtime`, `client2.dimtime` and so on. My goal was to do as much as possible in SQL. In other function I get schema names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.schemata`. So the `INSERT` must be in `schema_update` function and must be called within the context of a specific schema.

Comment: @Nux: Yes, you need dynamic SQL in that case. But use my simplified query. One query is substantially cheaper than two.