# Put several INSERT statements into a stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have several insert requests like below:

```
insert into dummy (col1,col2) SELECT 'aa',one_col FROM another_table;
insert into dummy (col1,col2) SELECT 'bb',another_col FROM another_table;
```

I would like to put them in a single stored procedure and run it once in a while.

Alas, I found nothing relevant on the net. I don't want to return a value therefore creating a function is useless to me. I think that using `WITH` will not help.

If you have any clues, I'm willing to take it.

Comment: What is the part causing you difficulty?  Why don't you simply read what you say you want to do and try it?

Comment: Hey Dan, in oracle you have something like `CREATE PROCEDURE ...`. Do you have something similar in `postgres`?

Comment: No `create function..` is your way irrespective of whether you want or dont want to return anything.

Comment: Hi Akmas, I don't want to return anything. Let me have a try. If I cannot do anything, I'll return with a post. Thanks.

Comment: Dan, thanks for the kick. Never done that but never too late too learn.

Comment: A subtle, but important detail: is `another_table` supposed to be the same table in multiple calls? Also, aren't there any `WHERE` conditions? And if so, do you select the same rows from `another_table` multiple times?

Comment: Hi Erwin, there are `where` clauses but I do not put them here because I did not think it was relevant.

Comment: @AndyK: The `WHERE` conditions are relevant, as is my first question above, your version of Postgres, table definitions, cardinalities and the general use case ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with a [PL/pgSQL function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html), but for "a call once in a while" and only plain SQL statements, [`LANGUAGE sql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html) is the more appropriate format. Detailed discussion when to use either:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_insert() 
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
   WITH sel AS (SELECT one_col, another_col FROM another_table WHERE <some_condition>)
   ,   ins1 AS (INSERT INTO dummy (col1,col2) SELECT 'aa', one_col FROM sel)
   INSERT INTO dummy (col1,col2) SELECT 'bb', another_col FROM sel;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql
```

The [CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) can be a bit more expensive due to materializing the set from the first `SELECT` - or not, if that actually saves selecting the rows multiple times, like separate `INSERT` statements would.

You probably want all your `INSERT` statements in the same batch to be based off the same snapshot. In case there can be **concurrent write operation**, the CTEs would guarantee that, because the whole query is based on the **same snapshot** of all involved tables.

If concurrency is not a problem and the `SELECT` is cheap (or not the same), simple, separate INSERTs may be faster.

Comment: Hi Erwin, happy new year. As you have understood, I'm newbie in `pl/sql`. Can you be more explicit in your explanation, please?

Comment: "pl/sql" is the name of the procedural language in Oracle. In Postgres you have PL/pgSQL, [quite a few other procedural server-side languages](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xplang.html) - or SQL functions, but not "pl/sql". You find more explanation in the [linked answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561). I added another link for "CTE". There are *many* related answers here, skim the plpgsql tag. It's often best to start with the excellent manual, I added links.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by seriously reading the manual

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_insert() 
returns void AS
$$
BEGIN
    insert into dummy (col1,col2) SELECT 'aa',one_col FROM another_table;
    insert into dummy (col1,col2) SELECT 'bb',another_col FROM another_table;
END;
$$ language plpgsql
```

Then execute it by typing

```
SELECT "my_insert"()
```

@Dan: Thanks for the kick. Yes I can ! : D

Comment: NOTE: you don't need language `plpgsql` here; it can be done in plain `sql` .

Comment: Hi @wildplasser, I just tried with `sql` instead of `plpgsql`and it is giving me an error ...

Comment: Just understood your comment. Can you give your solution, please?

Comment: Maybe I could, but I won't. It would probably cost me 15 minutes to set up your tables (whose defintions you did not add to your question) plus a few more to get the function into shape. Besides: you would not learn anything from copying my answer, or somebody elses. Sorry! BTW: the `FROM someothertable` seems to miss a WHERE-clause.

Comment: That's fine .  My solution may not be the best but it is working.  Most likely I've could use `with` but I will have someone who knows nothing about sql,  so I need an almost push button. Thank you for answering,  I appreciate.

Comment: The solution to writing the function in sql as opposed to plpgsql is to remove the BEGIN and END statements.