# PostgreSQL: create two functions or add a parameter to an existing function?

Tags: performance, postgresql, user-defined-functions, postgresql-performance

Suppose I have a not trivial query to return a list of places from a given name piece e.g. "Rio" would return both "Rio de Janeiro" and "Rio Negro". But in one place I would need a short version like "Rio Negro/BR" while in other I would have "Rio Negro (Gazetteer, Amazonas, Brasil)".

What is the optimal solution in PostgreSQL: create two smaller functions or one bigger?

The bigger function would be called from two different sources, each time running one of two similar SQL requests, both large.

Maybe if I split it in two different functions it will become faster?

Comment: What's the parameter you would add to the function ? just a boolean or something more meaningfull ?

Comment: If I need to choose between only two options, it may be a boolean. But for the future I might have more than two, then I would use a short int or a char.

Answer (score 0):

Two specialized functions are typically faster than one combined function if you just have to call one of them. If you'd have to call *both* specialized functions, it's the other way round: then it's typically faster to execute a single combined function. It depends on your actual use case.

There might be rare corner cases, for instance if the function is called only a few times per session. Then it might turn out to be faster to reuse the same combined function for small functions with saved query plans. (PL/pgSQL functions re-use query plans within the same session. SQL functions don't). The overhead might be more expensive for two separate functions. But that's an academic exception. Related:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)
- [PostgreSQL Stored Procedure Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684)