# How does T-SQL not clearly distinguish between procedural code and "plain SQL"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

From a great reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/50859647/156458

> The only DBMS product which does **not clearly distinguish between procedural code and "plain SQL"** is SQL Server: T-SQL is an extension to the SQL language which allows you to **mix "regular SQL" and procedural SQL without telling the backend that the code needs a different engine to run** (which is a source of great **confusion for people migrating from SQL Server to Postgres or Oracle**).

I was wondering how T-SQL does not clearly distinguish between procedural code and "plain SQL"?

How does that cause confusion to PostgreSQL users?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe in T-SQL 'procedural code' refers to actual stored procedures. So anything after `CREATE PROCEDURE sp_myProcedure` is considered 'procedural code'

Comment: `... which allows you to mix "regular SQL" and procedural SQL without telling the backend` implies that the SQL language is extended (*polluted!*) with non-sql elements. (such as: variables,assignments,conditions) And it does *not* confuse Postgres users, it confuses tsql users who switch to Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was referring to the fact that in SQL Server you can write:

```
declare @some_variable

if exists (select ..) then 
  ... do something
else 
  ... do something else
end

... do more ..
```

without the need to "formally" start a block of procedural code as it is required in Postgres (using `DO`)  or Oracle (using `DECLARE`). Variables can also be used in that code (again unlike Oracle and Postgres, where variables can **only** be used a procedural block)

That code is also allowed to run a SELECT statement without the requirement to store the result somewhere (as it is in Postgres, Oracle, DB2, and many other DBMS)

---

I also never said it (the separation) confuses Postgres (or Oracle) users.

I wrote "it confuses users *migrating* **from** SQL Server **to** Postgres (or Oracle").

For an experienced SQL Server user the clear (and sometimes annoying indeed) distinction between SQL and procedural language (PL/pgSQL or PL/SQL) is at least surprising, if not completely off-putting. I have seen people being extremely mad about that (not to say p* off) to the extent that they claimed "*that such a database is unusable*"