# Using WITH Clause and "RETURN QUERY SELECT" Together

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem using WITH clause and "RETURN QUERY SELECT" together.
I tried the following "simplified" function, but got an error.  How can I return result-set from WITH clause statement?

```
CREATE FUNCTION f1() RETURNS TABLE(v1 varchar, v2 varchar)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$                 
BEGIN   
    WITH tbl AS 
    (
        SELECT 'a' AS aa , 'b' AS bb     
    )
    RETURN QUERY SELECT aa as v1, bb as v2 from tbl
END;   
$$;



ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN"
LINE 10:     RETURN QUERY SELECT aa as v1, bb as v2 from tbl
             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 215
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RETURN QUERY` comes before `with` as a CTE is part of the query.
A semicolon is missing after the end of the query.
Unrelated but better use `text` data type. Here is the same function corrected.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1()
RETURNS TABLE(v1 text, v2 text) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$                 
BEGIN   
    RETURN QUERY 
    WITH tbl AS 
    (
        SELECT 'a' AS aa, 'b' AS bb     
    )
    SELECT aa as v1, bb as v2 from tbl;
END;   
$$;

select * from f1();
```

| v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |

Comment: The function is also simple enough to be `language sql` instead of `language plpgsql`, which would let it lose the `begin`, `return query` and `end;` altogether. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771561/5298879)'s on the benefits of selecting one function `language` over the other. I +1'd already - even in the current form, it already solves the problem and provides useful additional info.