# Order a query with Specification and Criteria Builder with a Postgres JSONB attribute as a number

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

Got a table in a postgres database with a jsonb column and needed to order a query using a specific key in the json as a numeric value, it is possible with native sql:

```
select key->>value from table where order by CAST(key->>value AS DECIMAL);
```

But with specification it is no possible directly, so I've encapsulate the operator **CAST** in a function and call it when building the order clause in the specification factory.

```
create or replace function cast_number(str varchar)
   returns real
   language plpgsql
  as
$$
declare 
new_number real;
begin
 select cast(str as decimal)
 into new_number;
 return new_number;
end;
```

and I call it using CriteriaBuilder::function after calling **jsonb_extract_path_text** also via criteria builder.
Still no sure about the performance here tbh

Did not found anything about this anywhere, so I want to share my solution and see what people think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What you want is possible with native sql and is possible directly. I am not sure where you thought directly was not possible but perhaps from your query itself. It is invalid and would be so even without the data being Json. You have a `where` clause but no predicates after it. The structure `where order...` is invalid. But a direct cast would in `order by` is valid whit a valid `where` clause. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/371LssXv)).  
As far as encapsulating the cast in a function there is nothing wrong with doing so. However, you can substantially reduce the complexity by creating a SQL function instead of an pgplsql one, and has [other advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions); see selected answer. Your function rewritten as SQL function: (also in demo)

```
create or replace function cast_number(str varchar)
    returns decimal
    immutable
    language sql
as $$
   select cast(str as decimal);
$$;
```

NOTE:

- immutable added but not essential (check it out)
- changed return type to match cast. Not required but a good habit to form matching what is actually returned to the declared return type.