# Query returned more than one row from INSERT ... RETURNING in function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a function that inserts multiple records from a SELECT statement and then returns the inserted ids to the caller, but I keep getting the error

> ERROR: query returned more than one row, CONTEXT:

Here's a simplified version of the function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.copy_data(arg_client_id CHAR(30))
RETURNS TABLE (dest_id CHAR(30))
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY INVOKER
AS $$
DECLARE 
    -- Declare a variable to store the inserted IDs
    inserted_ids CHAR(30)[];
BEGIN
    WITH
    cte_1 AS (...),

    cte_2 AS (...)

    INSERT INTO schema.dest
    (client_id, fk_id, ...)
    SELECT client_id, fk_id, ...
    FROM
        cte_1
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM cte_2
            WHERE
                cte_1.client_id = cte_2.client_id
                AND cte_1.fk_id = cte_2.fk_id
                AND ...
        )
    RETURNING schema.dest.dest_id INTO inserted_ids;

    RETURN QUERY SELECT dest_id FROM UNNEST(inserted_ids) AS dest_id;
END
$$
;
```

I'm honestly stumped, I couldn't find anything relevant in the Postgres docs or on SO.
And ChatGPT doesn't seem to be able to solve this one either (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to shoehorn a *set* into an *array* variable, which does not work like that.

Instead, return the set directly. While being at it, simplify to a plain SQL function, no need for PL/pgSQL here.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.copy_data(arg_client_id char(30))
  RETURNS TABLE (dest_id char(30))  -- avoid char(n)
  LANGUAGE sql AS  -- SECURITY INVOKER was noise - default anyway
$func$
WITH cte_1 AS (...)
   , cte_2 AS (...)
INSERT INTO my_schema.dest (client_id, fk_id, ...)
SELECT client_id, fk_id, ...
FROM   cte_1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM cte_2  -- SELECT list can stay empty
   WHERE  cte_1.client_id = cte_2.client_id
   AND    cte_1.fk_id = cte_2.fk_id
   AND ...
  )
RETURNING dest.dest_id;  -- don't prefix schema-name!
$func$;
```

You most probably don't need CTEs either, and the whole query may be even simpler, yet.

Matching your given `char(30)` - which is almost always a bad choice for a data type:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Comment: Fantastic answer Erwin! Thanks a lot. Three notes: (1) Can you comment as to why LANGUAGE is sql and not plpgsql (and have a link to an explanation if possible), (2) There is an extra parenthesis in the args that you can remove, (3) In my case, the value is a CHAR(30), and PostgreSQL complains that my return value mismatches the declared return type if I put TEXT. Also, the ctes are necessary, I use window functions in the actual query :) ; Finally, thanks for the extra tips in your code comments :)

Comment: About `LANGUAGE sql` vs. `LANGUAGE plpgsql`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771561/939860 It's not important in this case. SQL is just simpler and, since you are struggeling already, probably the better choice.