How to call a Postgres procedure from spring criteria API
I am using SpringBoot 3 and postgres 15. I saved a function in postgres that return a table with 5 column and I want to call it in java using criteria API.
But when I try to call my function, I have a PSQLException :
2024-08-29T11:32:51.877+02:00 ERROR 25296 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults [ERREUR: la procédure statvrp(unknown, unknown) n'existe pas
  Indice : Aucune procédure ne correspond au nom donné et aux types d'arguments.
Vous pourriez avoir besoin d'ajouter des conversions de type explicites.
  Position : 6] [HikariProxyCallableStatement@806296137 wrapping call statVRP(('2010-01-01 00:00:00+01'),('2023-05-30 23:59:59+02'))]; SQL [HikariProxyCallableStatement@806296137 wrapping call statVRP(('2010-01-01 00:00:00+01'),('2023-05-30 23:59:59+02'))]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: la procédure statvrp(unknown, unknown) n'existe pas
  Indice : Aucune procédure ne correspond au nom donné et aux types d'arguments.
Vous pourriez avoir besoin d'ajouter des conversions de type explicites.
  Position : 6

Here is my code for the sql function :
create or replace function statVRP(dateDebut timestamp, dateFin timestamp)
    returns table
        (
            idfamille int,
            libelle varchar(50),
            idcode_vendeur int,
            nom_vendeur varchar(50),
            total_ht real
        )
    language plpgsql
as
$$ begin
    return query (
        select stat.idfamille, stat.libelle, stat.idcode_vendeur, stat.nom_vendeur, sum(stat.total_ht)
        from (
        (select distinct f1_0.idfamille,f1_0.libelle,cv1_0.idcode_vendeur,cv1_0.nom_vendeur, sum(t1_0.total_ht) as total_ht 
        from code_vendeur cv1_0 join ticket t1_0 on cv1_0.idcode_vendeur=t1_0.idcode_vendeur,famille f1_0 
        where t1_0.date_ticket between dateDebut and dateFin 
        and t1_0.numero_ticket is not null group by f1_0.idfamille, cv1_0.idcode_vendeur order by idfamille)
        union
        (select distinct f1_0.idfamille,f1_0.libelle,cv1_0.idcode_vendeur,cv1_0.nom_vendeur, sum(f2_0.total_ht) as total_ht
        from code_vendeur cv1_0 join facture f2_0 on cv1_0.idcode_vendeur=f2_0.idcode_vendeur,famille f1_0 
        where f2_0.date_facture between dateDebut and dateFin
        group by f1_0.idfamille, cv1_0.idcode_vendeur order by idfamille)
        ) as stat
        group by 1, 3, 2, 4
        order by 1, 3 asc
    );

end; $$;


And here is my java code to call it :
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("statVRP")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("dateDebut", Timestamp.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("dateFin", Timestamp.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                        .setParameter("dateDebut", criteria.dateDebut()).setParameter("dateFin", criteria.dateFin());
        query.execute();

        return (List<VenteVRPDTO>) query.getResultList();

I would precise that my DTO is not an entity.

maybe you could have a look at the second answer of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/language-sql-vs-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions to see the difference between sql and plpgsql syntax.

Thank you, I just read it and change my function from plpgsql to sql, but I still have the same error. It doesn't seem to be the cause of the exception.
